# Data model versioning and relationship management

Tags: json, mongodb, version

**PROBLEM**

I am developing an app where the data model will be very similar to JSFiddle's. A user will create a new entry that will be assigned a GUID in the database. My question is how to handle when other users want to modify/fork/version the original entry. JSFiddle handles this by versioning the entry (so the URL becomes something like jsfiddle.net/GUID/1).

What is the benefit to JSFiddle's method over assigning a new GUID to the modified version and just recording a relationship to the original entry in the database?

It seems like no matter what I will have to create a new entry in the database that will essentially be a modified copy of the original.

Also, there will be both registered and anonymous users just like JSFiddle. The registered users should be able to log in and see all of their own entries and possibly the versions/forks that exist off of their own entries (though this isn't currently a requirement).

Am I missing something? Is there a right and wrong way to do this?

**TECH**

Using parse.com's RESTful API for data CRUD; node on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the benefit to JSFiddle's method over assigning a new GUID to the modified version and just recording a relationship to the original entry in the database?

I would imagine none, both would require the same copy operation and the same double query (in MongoDB) to get the parent.

The only difference is what field you go by.

> Am I missing something?

Not that I can see.

> Is there a right and wrong way to do this?

It seems as though you have this pretty well covered frankly.

MVCC does seem the right way to do this in some respects, however you don't have to go the full hog. If you were there might be cause for you to change to a database that has it built in like CouchDB or something because MongoDBs implementation would be on top of its current existing lock mechanisms, its like adding a lock on a lock.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm a JS developer, so understanding deeper data model relationships isn't a strength of mine. It's good to know I'm on the right track.